# Where do we instantiate view and presenter in Passive View on WinForm?

Tags: .net, winforms, mvp

I am new to Passive view, I would like to know if we have master and detail form on WinForm application. So when the user clicks on master's button, it will shows the detail form. Where do we instantiate view and presenter? I don't think, we instantiate at code behind of form. But if we instantiate at presenter's method, it means we couple our presenter with form view. Is there any good examples or frameworks of Passive View for building WinForm application .Net?